# if condition SQL queires

Tags: sql

I am very new to sql.I am trying to write if condition query in sql. by using this if condition we  need to update the records in sql.but unfortunately we got some errors in while doing  process of sql.

This is my query:
**AS
BEGIN
if id ='101' 
update date
set name='ind'
from data**

could please tell me the query along with example.

Comment: I think you are looking for a `where` clause.

Comment: `UPDATE tablename SET columnname = value WHERE...`.

Answer (score 0):

To provide a full answer that can be marked as correct, I will restate @jarlh's answer and @Gordon's suggestion:

```
UPDATE data
SET name = 'ind'
WHERE id = '101'
```